# Function that creates a drop down menu

Tags: javascript, html

So the first thing i have to say, this is for school and I'm not allowed to use  JQuery and such things.

What i want to do is, to write a function that creates when I call it a drop down menu with a specific length, for a drop down menu for dates.

```
        function date(start, end) {

        var dateV ="";

        for(i=start;i<=end;i++)
            dateV += "<option value='"+i+"'>"+i+"</option>";

        document.write(dateV);
    }
```

The Vars start and end are for the loop, as an example for the year i use 1900 as start and 2014 as end.

This function is written in an **external File**(how we are supposed to do it) but it **isn't working**. But it is **working** if i write this function **in the HTML Header**

I tried to call it like this:

```
            Day:
        <select name="tag">
             <script type="text/javascript" src="myjsfile.js">
                date(1,31);
            </script>
        </select>
```

So know i would like to now why it isnt working in an external File but in the header.
Lots of people already told me that  `document.write()` could be the problem. if this is the problem what other function could i use?.

EDIT:

How i call it:

```
        <select name="tag" id="dd1">
             <script type="text/javascript">
                date(1,31,dd1);
            </script>
        </select>
```

And thats the function in an external file:

```
function date(start,end,div) {

var select1 = document.getElementById(div);

    for(i=start;i<=end;i++){
       var option = document.createElement("option");
       option.text = i;
       option.value= i;
       select1.add(option);
    }
}
```

The third new parameter is to keep it static because i need a dropdown menu for days, months and years and then i need a new id every time(or?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
           Day:

                <select name="tag" id="ddl">

                </select>


                <script>
                date(1,23);
                function date(start,end) 
                {

                        var select1 = document.getElementById("ddl");

                 for(i=start;i<=end;i++){
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                option.text = i;
                option.value= i;
                select1.add(option);
                }


                 }
                </script>
            Now its perfect JScript 
        Yes it does not use " $ " sign ,It is pure Javascript.There is no need of JQuery now.
        Explanation => 
        1)First i created variable "select1" which stores HTML element "ddl" (got it be its id).

        2)Then we have start and end value. So till the value ends , Create HTML element "option"  And store in it  i)Value to be in <option> tag and ii)Text in it.

        3) Then add that variable as child in the variable  "select1".


    //NEW CODE According to you
<html>
    <head>

    </head>

    <body>
        Day:
            <select name="tag" id="ddl">

            </select>


    <script src="stk.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script>
    date(1,23); 
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>

//stk.js

function date(start,end) 
{
var select1 = document.getElementById("ddl");
for(i=start;i<=end;i++){
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.text = i;
option.value = i;
select1.add(option);
}               
}
```

Comment: read `OP` question carefully, he don't want to include jQuery

Comment: Should i explain what i did?

Comment: yeah, please. is it now jquery "free"?because it looks like

Comment: somehow not working i edit the main post to show you how i call it

Comment: You mean myjsfile.js Contains function?

Comment: yeah, sorry if i didnt explain this properly

Comment: this is the external js file http://pastebin.com/tr68YRw5 all the different kinds of date() are now "disabled" as comments

Comment: why arent u calling the date function in the html file and why are u calling it in the external file. this makes no sense to me because i want it to be dynamic and not always start with one and end with 31 for amonth. i need it for months and years etc

Comment: ok now i modified code as per your need ,check for  code named //NEW CODE According to you

Comment: Now date is called in HTML

Comment: when i use it how u wrote it it doesnt work but there is something strange i want to tell you. i use an IDE for JS called Webstorm 7. It has a feature where i can enter the current project in a browser. If i call the index.html with this feature the drop down menu works(my drop down menu). but if i open it through windows explorer it doesnt work...

Comment: Which URL you are opening ? and provide URL(Web site address you see in Browser top ,When you open Through 1)Web storm 2)Windows explorer .

Comment: 1.Web Storm: http://localhost:63342/Basics/AdvancedBasics.html 2.Windows Explorer: C:\Users\Jakob\Desktop\Basics2\AdvancedBasics.html

Comment: Obviously , localhost process page ,and dynamic data ,So when you see localhost in Browser bar its correct.Here PC works as server ,and its correct ,no need to worry. The website does processing via localhost path only.Like say there is "http://www" before google.com ,Same is with localhost.And your code is working ,See ,other people are not going to open Your application on Their PC using Your windows explorer(which is in your PC).They will go for localhost ,or  http://  ,Got it ? ITs correct with your code!

Answer (score 0):

You can manage this way, try this code

Add id in HTML code

```
    <select name="tag" id="dd"></select>
```

javascript

```
<script>

      function date(start, end) {

    var dateV ="";

    for(i=start;i<=end;i++)
        dateV += "<option value='"+i+"'>"+i+"</option>";
    document.getElementById('dd').innerHTML = dateV;

}
date(1, 10);
</script>
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Urk7u/1/)

Comment: somehow i think im very dumb, you both give me code that should work but it isnt working...

Comment: @Jakab please demo link in bottom of answer